# Get value of href attribute of <a> tag without jQuery

Tags: javascript, href

Is any way, how to without jQuery get from string value of href attribute in "a" tag?
I have got string with (for example) this content - `<a href="www.something">`.

How can I get value of href attribute to variable?

Comment: Are you starting with a string or a DOM element ? If you have the DOM element simply do `var href = a.href;`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> *I have got string with (for example) this content* - `<a href="www.something">`

If it is actually in a string as follows:

```
var s = '<a href="www.something">';
```

Then you can use a regex with the [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
var href = s.match(/href="([^"]*)/)[1];
// href is now www.something
```

If it is an element on your page then have a look at [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17488629/615754) (no need for me to duplicate that information here).

Comment: Good things happen when we team up. :-)

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. I've upgraded my mention of your answer to an actual hyperlink. +1 on your answer.

Comment: (Sorry, @T.J.Crowder, but no. I wouldn't have mentioned your answer if I didn't think it was worth a vote, but somehow I forgot to actually press the button earlier. An extra bonus for you now, I guess.)

Answer (score 11):

If you really have that *as a string*, then [refer to nnnnnn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17488655/157247).

Or alternately, if you're in the browser environment:

```
var str = '<a href="www.something">';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str + "</a>"; // Make it a complete tag
var link = div.firstChild.getAttribute("href");
```

---

If you have an actual element on a page created via that markup, then:

If you have a reference to the element, you can get the `href` from it like this:

```
var link = theElement.href;
// or
var link = theElement.getAttribute("href");
```

Getting it via `getAttribute` returns the actual attribute's value rather than the fully-qualified version, and the `href` reflected property gets the fully-qualified version (e.g., relative links get expanded).

Getting a reference to the element is a broad topic. If it has an `id`, you can use `getElementById`. Or if you're responding to an event and the event is happening on an element near the one you want, you can use various [DOM properties and methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) to navigate to it. With [a lot of modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), you can use CSS selectors and either `querySelector` (find one element) or `querySelectorAll` (a list).

For instance, this gives you the `href` of the first link on the page that has the class `"foo"`:

```
console.log(document.querySelector("a.foo").href);
```

Full example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/itiyuj/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/itiyuj/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Getting the Link</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="theLink" href="/relative/link">Link</a>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var theLink = document.getElementById("theLink");
      display("<code>href</code> property: " + theLink.href);
      display("<code>getAttribute('href')</code>: " +
              theLink.getAttribute("href"));

      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will loop over all `<a/>` elements and log their `href` value (if they have one):

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var i, len = anchors.length;

for( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    console.log(anchors[i].getAttribute('href'));
}
```